# Add separate columns into a dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am trying to add data from a split range (X5:X?,AX5:AX?) into a VBA dictionary. ? Is determined as the last row of data within the sheet. I am new to VBA and trying to force my way through this.

```
Public Sub Test
'Creates a dictionary object
 Dim orderstatus As Object, path As String
 Set orderstatus = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Dim order, status 'key and object names
 order = "Order #": status = "Order Status"
 path = ThisWorkbook.path

'Central District--A Head Water Order Summary
 Dim app As New Excel.Application, book As Excel.Workbook
 app.Visible = False
 Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(path & "\CENTRAL DIST\A HEAD - WATER ORDER SUMMARY.xls")


'A Head #1
 Dim A1Head As Integer, last As Integer, l as Integer
 l = 4
 book.Worksheets("A HEAD #1").Activate
 last = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set lastCol = Range("X5:X" & last, "AX5:AX" & last)
 For Each l In lastCol.Cells
    orderstatus.Add lastCol.Value
 Next
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim OrderStatus As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set OrderStatus = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CENTRAL DIST\A HEAD - WATER ORDER SUMMARY.xls").Sheets("A HEAD #1")
        For i = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
            If Not OrderStatus.Exists(.Cells(i, "X").Value) Then OrderStatus(.Cells(i, "X").Value) = .Cells(i, "AX").Value
        Next i
        .Parent.Close False
    End With

    'Print dictionary to text file
    Close #1
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\OrderStatus Output.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Key" & vbTab & "Value"
    For Each Key In OrderStatus.Keys
        Print #1, Key & vbTab & OrderStatus(Key)
    Next Key
    Close #1

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to paste the dictionary into a txt file?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
orderstatus.Add lastCol.Value
```

to this

```
orderstatus.Add l.Value, 1
```

This assumes you will have no duplicates because you aren't checking for that and will get an error if you do have duplicates.

Comment: This throws a 450 error:  wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: dictionary needs a key and a value: `orderstatus.Add l.Value, l.Value`

Comment: How do you define column X values as the key and AX as the value?

Answer (score 0):

you're messing up with `Range` object and `Row` index

and you'd better abandon the `Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern and use fully qualified range references

give this code a try

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    'Creates a dictionary object
    Dim orderstatus As Object
    Set orderstatus = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Central District--A Head Water Order Summary
    Dim app As New Excel.Application, book As Excel.Workbook
    app.Visible = False
    Set book = app.Workbooks.Add(ThisWorkbook.path & "\CENTRAL DIST\A HEAD - WATER ORDER SUMMARY.xls")

    'A Head #1
    Dim dataRng As Range, r As Range
    Dim last As Integer
    With book.Worksheets("A HEAD #1")
        For Each r In .Range("X5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp))
           orderstatus(r.value) = r.Offset(, 26).value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Moreover if you're running this macro from within an Excel session already, you don't need to get another instance of it nor explicitly reference it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    'Creates a dictionary object
    Dim orderstatus As Object
    Set orderstatus = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Central District--A Head Water Order Summary
    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = Workbooks.Add(ThisWorkbook.path & "\CENTRAL DIST\A HEAD - WATER ORDER SUMMARY.xls")

    'A Head #1
    Dim dataRng As Range, r As Range
    Dim last As Integer
    With book.Worksheets("A HEAD #1")
        For Each r In .Range("X5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp))
           orderstatus(r.value) = r.Offset(, 26).value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```